# What is a good "backoff" algorithm for throttling logging of errors?

Tags: c++

I came up with one that only triggers on every 10, 20, 30... 100, 200, 300..., 1000, 2000, but I want to see if there is a better way to do this.

```
unsigned long fails = 0;

while (true) {
    if (!checkSomething()) {
        fails++;
        unsigned long backoff = exp10(((unsigned long) log10(fails)));
        if (fails % backoff == 0)
            logError("...");
    }
}
```

Comment: A technique I've seen that works well is just to log `occured N times` where it's understood that that refers to a particular time window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems reasonable.  Another way would be to enqueue the log somewhere in memory and de-duplicate on a timer.  For example, every ten seconds you could count the number of occurrences of each message and log them all.  This overcomes one issue with your approach, which is that if the event happens 10 times, then five hours go by, then it happens once per hour afterward, it won't appear for another ten hours.  It's nice to "flush the buffer" of log messages from time to time, so that you don't lose operational awareness.